# Create DataSource from JDBC URL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

It can be handy to pass the path, username, password and all the options in a single string to create a connection to a database.
Is there a way to create a DataSource object from a single URL? Maybe it is possible to create a DataSource from an open SQL connection?

```java
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?user=root&password=123&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Comment: Where are you getting the string from, and why is it necessary for it to all be in a single String, as opposed to a Properties object?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to create a DataSource object from a single URL?

For what it's worth, this seems to work for MySQL Connector/J:

```java
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb";

com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource mds =
        new com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource();
mds.setUrl(connectionUrl);
```

> Maybe it is possible to create a DataSource from an open SQL connection?

Maybe it is. You could try retrieving the connection URL via

```java
conn.getMetaData().getURL()
```

and proceed as above.